# Recover mysql database following MacOS upgrade

Tags: mysql, mamp, macos-monterey

So I've had the great idea yesterday to upgrade my Mac to MacOS Monterey only to discover that it didn't have PHP installed on it anymore.

I was working on a PHP website, had phpmyadmin installed and all... I thought I could just install php again, easy peasy. But no. Long story short, I installed MAMP and now it works again, BUT I've lost my mySQL database... I have a partial backup but it would be a pain to go through all the things I've changed since.

Is there any way to recover the old one? Because I think MAMP is not using the same instance of mySQL.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
/Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/(MAMP version)/db/(mysql version)
```

It could be that by reinstalling, you lost the DB files, or perhaps not. Check and see if there is anything to salvage

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually, I didn't have MAMP before. Everything was working fine with PHP and Apache by default... So it's just that MAMP uses a different db from the one I had before and I'm not sure how to recover this non-MAMP db.

Comment: Then check the DB location of the previous installation. The files should be there. Then look at this: https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/how-to-recover-corrupt-mysql-database/

Comment: The thing is, I don't know where the files are located... I've tried /usr/local/mysql/data but I can't access it (even with sudo)...